# Parse JS file via Python

Tags: javascript, python, parsing

have a question, how can I properly get the value for field '*data*' from the following JS file via Python? Tried do it like parsing a json, but for *json.load* it's in incorrect format. So will be thankful for a help.

```
return [
{
    'id'         : 1, 
    'category'   : 'html5', 
    'name'       : {
        'en' : 'XSS via formaction - requiring user interaction (1)',
        'ja' : 'formaction\u7d4c\u7531\u3067\u306eXSS - \u30e6\u30fc\u30b6\u306e\u4ecb\u5728\u304c\u5fc5\u8981',
        'ru' : 'ÐŸÐ°ÑÑÐ¸Ð²Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ ÑÐºÑ€Ð¸Ð¿Ñ‚Ð¸Ð½Ð³ Ñ‡ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ· formaction (1)',
        'cs' : 'XSS pomocÃ­ formaction - vyÅ¾aduje uÅ¾ivatelskou interakci (1)',
        'de' : '',
        'tr' : 'formaction ile XSS - kullanÄ±cÄ± etkileÅŸimi gerektiren (1)',
        'zh' : 'é€šè¿‡formactionå±žæ€§è¿›è¡ŒXSS - éœ€è¦ç”¨æˆ·è¿›è¡Œäº¤äº’ (1)'
    },
    'data'       : '<form id="test"></form><button form="test" formaction="%js_uri_alert%">X</button>',
    'trigger'    : 'document.getElementsByTagName("button")
    'urls'    : ['http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fs-formaction'],
    'howtofix'   : {
        'en' : 'Don\'t allow users to submit markup containing "form" and "formaction" attributes or transform them to bogus attributes. Avoid "id" attributes for forms as well as submit buttons.',
    'ja' : '\u0022form\u0022\u3068\u0022formaction\u0022\u5c5e\u6027\u3092\u542b\u3080\u8981\u7d20\u3092\u30e6\u30fc\u30b6\u306b\u5165\u529b\u3055\u305b\u306a\u3044\u3001\u3042\u308b\u3044\u306f\u305d\u308c\u3089\u306e\u5c5e\u6027\u3092\u7121\u52b9\u306a\u5024\u306b\u5909\u63db\u3059\u308b\u3053\u3068\u3002\u0022id\u0022\u5c5e\u6027\u306fform\u3060\u3051\u3067\u306a\u304fsubmit\u30dc\u30bf\u30f3\u306b\u3064\u3044\u3066\u3082\u5bfe\u5fdc\u3059\u308b\u3053\u3068\u3002',
        'ru' : 'ÐÐµ Ñ€Ð°Ð·Ñ€ÐµÑˆÐ°Ð¹Ñ‚Ðµ Ð¿Ð¾Ð»ÑŒÐ·Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ‚ÐµÐ»ÑŒÑÐºÑƒÑŽ Ñ€Ð°Ð·Ð¼ÐµÑ‚ÐºÑƒ, ÑÐ¾Ð´ÐµÑ€Ð¶Ð°Ñ‰ÑƒÑŽ Ð°Ñ‚Ñ€Ð¸Ð±ÑƒÑ‚Ñ‹ form Ð¸ formaction Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ Ð½ÐµÐ¿Ñ€Ð°Ð²Ð¸Ð»ÑŒÐ½Ñ‹Ðµ Ð·Ð½Ð°Ñ‡ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ ÑÑ‚Ð¸Ñ… Ð°Ñ‚Ñ€Ð¸Ð±ÑƒÑ‚Ð¾Ð². Ð˜Ð·Ð±ÐµÐ³Ð°Ð¹Ñ‚Ðµ Ð°Ñ‚Ñ€Ð¸Ð±ÑƒÑ‚ id Ð² Ñ„Ð¾Ñ€Ð¼Ð°Ñ…, ÐºÐ°Ðº Ð¸ ÑÐ»ÐµÐ¼ÐµÐ½Ñ‚Ñ‹ Ð²Ð²Ð¾Ð´Ð° submit Ñ‚Ð¸Ð¿Ð°.',
        'cs' : 'Nedovolte uÅ¾ivatelÅ¯m vloÅ¾it kÃ³d obsahujÃ­cÃ­ atributy "form" a "formaction" Äi jejich "zkomolenÃ©" tvary. VyhnÄ›te se atributu "id" u formulÃ¡Å™Å¯ i u odesÃ­lacÃ­ch tlaÄÃ­tek.',
        'de' : '',
        'tr' : 'KullanÄ±cÄ±larÄ±n "form" ve "formaction" markup\'larÄ±nÄ± yollamalarÄ± engellenmeli veya bu Ã¶zellikler kullanÄ±ÅŸsÄ±z hale getirilmelidir. Submit butonlarÄ±nda olduÄŸu gibi formlarda "id" Ã¶zelliklerinden kaÃ§Ä±nÄ±n.',
        'zh' : 'ä¸è¦è®©ç”¨æˆ·æäº¤åŒ…å« "form" å’Œ "formaction"å±žæ€§çš„æ ‡ç­¾.é¿å…åœ¨formä¸­å‡ºçŽ°idå±žæ€§åŠæäº¤æŒ‰é’®.'
    },
    'browsers'   : {
        'firefox' : ['4.0', 'latest'],
        'opera': ['10.5', 'latest'], 
        'chrome': ['10.0', 'latest'],
        'safari' : ['4.0.4', 'latest'],
        'internet explorer' : ['10', 'latest (inside form element)']
    },
    'tags'       : ['xss', 'html5', 'opera', 'chrome', 'firefox', 'formaction', 'javascript', 'button'],
    'reporter'   : '.mario'
}
]
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `but for json.load it's in incorrect format` and what error it shows? Have you tried to `json.replace('"', '\\"').replace("'", "\"")`-it (replace doublequotes with `\"` and singlequotes with doublequotes to match JSON requironments)?

Comment: Read it line by line and look for the string 'data'

Comment: The character encoding looks wrong

Answer (score 0):

You may look into JavaScript parsers, like [`slimit`](http://pythonhosted.org/slimit/) (working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25112034/771848)). Or, you can also extract the `data` key value with a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re

match = re.search(r"'data'\s+:\s+'(.*?)',", script, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

It has a syntax error; `'trigger': 'document.getElementsByTagName("button")` should end with `',`.

If that is fixed, and you remove `return` from the start, the data can be gotten like

```
import ast

struct = ast.literal_eval(your_string)
data = struct[0]['data']
```