# Scrape webpage no ajax calls made but data not in DOM

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I'm doing an exercise in scraping data from a website. For example, [ZocDoc](https://zocdoc.com). I'm trying to get a list of all insurance providers and their plans (You can access this information on their homepage in the insurance dropdown).

It appears that all data is loaded via a `<scipt>` tag when the page loads. When looking in the network tab there doesn't appear to be any network calls that returns JSON including the plan names. I am able to get all the insurance plans using with the following (It's messy, but it works).

```
  import requests
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
  resp = requests.get('https://zocdoc.com')
  long_str = str(soup.findAll('script')[17].string)
  pop = data.split("Popular Insurances")[1]
  json.loads(pop[pop.find("[["):pop.find("]]")+2])
```

In the HTML returned there are no insurance plans. I also don't see any requests in the network tab where the plans are sent back (there are a few backbone files). One url looks encoded but I'm not sure that that is it and I'm just overthinking this [url](https://www.zocdoc.com/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=2977d8d74f63d7f8fedbea018b7a1d05&ns=12).

I've also tried waiting for all the JS to load so the data is in the DOM using [dryscrape](http://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but still no plans in the HTML.

Is there a way to gather this information without having a crawler click on every insurance provider to get their plans?

Comment: The url you posted is encoded and it is simply the ordinal number of the text, which you can get back by changing the outer `eval` within the information to a `console.log`. Which will return more functions. So the last line will be: `console.log(eval('String.fromCharCode('+z+')'));})()` instead of `eval(eval('String.fromCharCode('+z+')'));})()`.

Comment: @CoryShay thanks for pointing that out. It looks like it's for cookies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the list of insurances is kept deep inside the `script` tag:

```
insuranceModel = new gs.CarrierGroupedSelect(gs.CarrierGroupedSelect.prototype.parse({
...
primary_options: {
        name: "Popular Insurances",
        group: "primary",
        options: [[300,"Aetna",2,0,1,0],[304,"Blue Cross Blue Shield",2,1,1,0],[307,"Cigna",2,0,1,0],[369,"Coventry Health Care",2,0,1,0],[358,"Medicaid",2,0,1,0],[322,"UniCare",2,0,1,0],[323,"UnitedHealthcare",2,0,1,0]]
    },
    secondary_options: {
        name: "All Insurances",
        group: "secondary",
        options: [[440,"1199SEIU",2,0,1,0],[876,"20/20 Eyecare Plan",2,0,1,1],...]
    }
...
```

You can, of course, dive into wonderful world of JavaScript code parsing in Python either with regular expressions or Javascript parsers like `slimit` ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25112034/771848)), but this might result into less hair on the head. Plus, the result solution would be quite fragile.

In this particular case, I think [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) is a *much better fit*. Complete working example - getting the popular insurances:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
insurance_dropdown = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "I'll choose my insurance later")))
insurance_dropdown.click()

for option in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[data-group=primary] + .ui-gs-option-set > .ui-gs-option"):
    print(option.get_attribute("data-value"))

driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
Aetna
Blue Cross Blue Shield
Cigna
Coventry Health Care
Medicaid
UniCare
UnitedHealthcare
```

Note that in this case the headless `PhantomJS` browser is used, but you can use Chrome or Firefox or other browsers that selenium has an available driver for.

Comment: yes, I can get the insurance providers, but not the plan name. Each of those providers also have plans. That's what I'm having trouble getting

Comment: an example plan is `ActiveCare 2`

Comment: @user2954587 gotcha, this would require clicking the insurances one by one and extracting the plans, I'll think of something and update you later. Thanks.

Comment: @user2954587 here is what I've got at this point: https://gist.github.com/alecxe/e13676a368449a5987e8ea3f3cb91675. It is randomly failing and needs tweaking and debugging, hope you can work on that. The dropdown is not exactly greatly handling the quick selenium clicks and there is a need to add artificial delays. Plus, some insurances have no plans - so this is a special case as well. Thanks.