# How to use Beautiful Soup to extract function string in <script> tag?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In a given .html page, I have a script tag like this:
How can I use beautiful soup to extract the "retrun" information under "function getData()" ?

```js
<script>
function getData()
{
 return "zip,city,state,MedianIncome,MedianIncomeRank,CostOfLivingIndex,CostOfLivingRank\n10452,Bronx,NY,20606,2,147.7,74";
}

function getResultsCount()
{
 return "1";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way, arguably the simplest, is to use a [regular expression](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) to both locate the element and to extract the desired string:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<script>
function getData()
{
    return "zip,city,state,MedianIncome,MedianIncomeRank,CostOfLivingIndex,CostOfLivingRank\n10452,Bronx,NY,20606,2,147.7,74";
}

function getResultsCount()
{
    return "1";
}

</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

pattern = re.compile(r'return "(.*?)";$', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

print(pattern.search(script.text).group(1))
```

Prints:

```
zip,city,state,MedianIncome,MedianIncomeRank,CostOfLivingIndex,CostOfLivingRank
10452,Bronx,NY,20606,2,147.7,74
```

---

Or, you can also use a JavaScript parser, like [`slimit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit), example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25112034/771848).

Comment: I got an error (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text') when I update the code like below.

url = "http://zipwho.com/?zip=91709&city=&filters=--_--_--_--&state=&mode=zip"
data = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

Comment: @jerry9855 first of all, should not the URL be `http://zipwho.com/?zip=91709&city=&filters=--_--_--_--&state=&mode=zip`? Also, you should switch from `html.parser` to `html5lib` (and have `html5lib` module installed).