# How to use Beautiful Soup to extract function string in <script> tag from a website?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In website page, How can I use beautiful soup to extract the "return" information under "function getData() in html source code" ?
I got error like this :

print(pattern.search(script.text).group(1))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

```js
import os, sys, urllib, urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://zipwho.com/?zip=91709&city=&filters=--_--_--_--&state=&mode=zip"
data = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
pattern = re.compile(r'return "(.*?)";$', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)
print(pattern.search(script.text).group(1))
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant html code as well?

Comment: if I assigned the html txt to "data" variable like below in python then works fine.  the issue is if I use "urlopen".    data="""  xxxxxxxxxxxx  """"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried it on my computer (with requests, not urllib2) and got this

```
print(script)
>>> None
```

This is why you get the

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Im not sure what your regex is trying to achieve but check it again.
Maybe test it on the string which u expect to get first

edit:
try this

```
url = "http://zipwho.com/?zip=91709&city=&filters=--_--_--_--&state=&mode=zip"
data = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
script = soup.find("script")
print(script.text)
```

the output:

```
function getData()
{
    return "zip,city,state,MedianIncome,MedianIncomeRank,CostOfLivingIndex,CostOfLivingRank,MedianMortgageToIncomeRatio,MedianMortgageToIncomeRank,OwnerOccupiedHomesPercent,OwnerOccupiedHomesRank,MedianRoomsInHome,MedianRoomsInHomeRank,CollegeDegreePercent,CollegeDegreeRank,ProfessionalPercent,ProfessionalRank,Population,PopulationRank,AverageHouseholdSize,AverageHouseholdSizeRank,MedianAge,MedianAgeRank,MaleToFemaleRatio,MaleToFemaleRank,MarriedPercent,MarriedRank,DivorcedPercent,DivorcedRank,WhitePercent,WhiteRank,BlackPercent,BlackRank,AsianPercent,AsianRank,HispanicEthnicityPercent,HispanicEthnicityRank\n91709,Chino Hills,CA,78336,96,260.8,93,25.6,92,84.9,81,6.4,90,37.5,87,44.9,88,66693,99,3.3,96,32.3,13,93.6,57,66.9,83,6.3,11,43.7,10,5.4,68,21.0,98,25.6,92";
}

function getResultsCount()
{
    return "1";
}
```

its a string

```
type(script.text)
>>><class 'str'>
```

so now you can easily match a regex against it to get the result you want

my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://zipwho.com/?zip=91709&city=&filters=--_--_--_--&state=&mode=zip"
data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, "html.parser")
script = soup.find('script')
print(script.text)
```

notice that im using requests instad of urllib2 (go ahead and try it)

Comment: I want to extract the "return" information under "function getData() in html source code.  <script>
function getData()
{
    return "zip,city,state,MedianIncome,MedianIncomeRank,CostOfLivingIndex,CostOfLivingRank\n10452,Bronx,NY,20606,2,147.7,74";
} </script>

Comment: im trying to work it out, i'll edit this in a few minutes

Comment: thank you for your help. is any way i can just get the "return" content under getData() function ? that is why I am trying to use regex.

Comment: From what i know, bs isn't capable of that so you have other options like the one i wrote above.

Comment: don't why. I still got the same error when i run your code.

Comment: and this might be useful as well
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111752/extracting-text-using-beautifulsoup-in-python/25112034#25112034)

Comment: print(script.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: for some reason i still got the same error even I run you code. It was running correctly when you post the solution. do I need to do anything to re-run your code ?

Comment: what version of python are you using?

did you make sure bs and requests are up to date? can you double check which version of them you are using?

also, instead of `print(script.text)`, do this : `print(soup.pretiffy())`, and post the results

Comment: print(soup.pretiffy())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: my python version is 2.7.6

Comment: please `print(data)` and upload the result

Comment: Well, this error indicates that "soup" == None, Did you try upgrade beautifulsoup and requests packages? If no, please do so as this error might be related to a version compatibility..

Comment: The issue was caused by network issue. They blocked my connection. Thank you for the help.