# Regex formula almost extracts JSON, but result is wrapped with extra data

Tags: python, regex

I found the following formula on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852187/beautifulsoup-extract-json-from-js) and slightly modified it which gets very close to the data, but now I’m not sure what regex adjustment to make.

The following code places the regex result (from html string) into `result`, which is *almost* the JSON, but it starts with `<script>\n    Spotify = {};\n    Spotify.Entity =` and ends with `;\n  </script>`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<html>...<script>{environment: "production",
                features: {}};
</script><script>
    Spotify = {};
    Spotify.Entity = {"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"followers":{"href":null,"total":273725},"genres":["art rock","brill building pop","british invasion","bubblegum pop","classic rock","folk rock","psychedelic rock","rock"],"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","popularity":60,"type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","top_tracks":[{"album":{"album_type":"album","artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/album\/7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/albums\/7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0","id":"7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0","name":"Odessey And Oracle","release_date":"1968-04-19","release_date_precision":"day","total_tracks":12,"type":"album","uri":"spotify:album:7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0"},"artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"disc_number":1,"duration_ms":214026,"explicit":false,"external_ids":{"isrc":"GBCBS6732269"},"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/track\/5AJrhrwz4oSZX2PwwV4qrN"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/tracks\/5AJrhrwz4oSZX2PwwV4qrN","id":"5AJrhrwz4oSZX2PwwV4qrN","is_local":false,"is_playable":true,"name":"Time Of The Season (Mono Version)","popularity":68,"preview_url":"https:\/\/p.scdn.co\/mp3-preview\/31274768646a1b5fd860ab3fcdf6b830587b5702?cid=162b7dc01f3a4a2ca32ed3cec83d1e02","track_number":12,"type":"track","uri":"spotify:track:5AJrhrwz4oSZX2PwwV4qrN"},{"album":{"album_type":"album","artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/album\/1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/albums\/1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4","id":"1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4","name":"Begin Here","release_date":"1965-03-01","release_date_precision":"day","total_tracks":14,"type":"album","uri":"spotify:album:1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4"},"artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"disc_number":1,"duration_ms":145293,"explicit":false,"external_ids":{"isrc":"GBCBS6432190"},"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/track\/3dzW0SoVNyJTWWJimX8stj"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/tracks\/3dzW0SoVNyJTWWJimX8stj","id":"3dzW0SoVNyJTWWJimX8stj","is_local":false,"is_playable":true,"name":"She's Not There","popularity":57,"preview_url":"https:\/\/p.scdn.co\/mp3-preview\/3a76321231fe16df6523a7af5d0b83ae23d7f566?cid=162b7dc01f3a4a2ca32ed3cec83d1e02","track_number":7,"type":"track","uri":"spotify:track:3dzW0SoVNyJTWWJimX8stj"},{"album":{"album_type":"album","artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/album\/7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/albums\/7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0","id":"7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0","name":"Odessey And Oracle","release_date":"1968-04-19","release_date_precision":"day","total_tracks":12,"type":"album","uri":"spotify:album:7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0"},"artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"disc_number":1,"duration_ms":127733,"explicit":false,"external_ids":{"isrc":"GBCBS6732267"},"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/track\/02KpkaZbiutsR0ucxce4Sh"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/tracks\/02KpkaZbiutsR0ucxce4Sh","id":"02KpkaZbiutsR0ucxce4Sh","is_local":false,"is_playable":true,"name":"This Will Be Our Year","popularity":55,"preview_url":"https:\/\/p.scdn.co\/mp3-preview\/a93e9a62c991068702928d0a74a5bd0c1a3fc72f?cid=162b7dc01f3a4a2ca32ed3cec83d1e02","track_number":9,"type":"track","uri":"spotify:track:02KpkaZbiutsR0ucxce4Sh"},{"album":{"album_type":"album","artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/album\/1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/albums\/1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4","id":"1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4","images":[{"height":640,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/d5a749a17dfde0529b66ed73bdb979c1b71da74e","width":640},{"height":300,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/a2a119315824287969a97952acdec142b18cbad8","width":300},{"height":64,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/37149c0c69e4237181894c3ac621488f125469e7","width":64}],"name":"Begin Here","release_date":"1965-03-01","release_date_precision":"day","total_tracks":14,"type":"album","uri":"spotify:album:1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4"},"artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"disc_number":1,"duration_ms":137733,"explicit":false,"external_ids":{"isrc":"GBCBS6432260"},"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/track\/7egTKPYxbWaaV1jEzb1rHu"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/tracks\/7egTKPYxbWaaV1jEzb1rHu","id":"7egTKPYxbWaaV1jEzb1rHu","is_local":false,"is_playable":true,"name":"Summertime","popularity":53,"preview_url":"https:\/\/p.scdn.co\/mp3-preview\/ad5fd12d797eca80f6da72bf37c74390710c699f?cid=162b7dc01f3a4a2ca32ed3cec83d1e02","track_number":2,"type":"track","uri":"spotify:track:7egTKPYxbWaaV1jEzb1rHu"},{"album":{"album_type":"album","artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/album\/7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/albums\/7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0","id":"7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0","images":[{"height":600,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/0a645e0d3298508d0a090474d998789bd06bfbae","width":600},{"height":300,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/5a2d17c24e4babc3604466e601641bc6341a1f32","width":300},{"height":64,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/3c4308f9778895e9c35f9fd63cb0b33fdf3b3b05","width":64}],"name":"Odessey And Oracle","release_date":"1968-04-19","release_date_precision":"day","total_tracks":12,"type":"album","uri":"spotify:album:7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0"},"artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"disc_number":1,"duration_ms":235826,"explicit":false,"external_ids":{"isrc":"GBCBS6732201"},"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/track\/5QXqz1KDz8Z8DmfQoxWmmy"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/tracks\/5QXqz1KDz8Z8DmfQoxWmmy","id":"5QXqz1KDz8Z8DmfQoxWmmy","is_local":false,"is_playable":true,"name":"Care Of Cell 44","popularity":51,"preview_url":"https:\/\/p.scdn.co\/mp3-preview\/dd50eb2d932bf1429b614d6a2ee894fa9a0f9fbd?cid=162b7dc01f3a4a2ca32ed3cec83d1e02","track_number":1,"type":"track","uri":"spotify:track:5QXqz1KDz8Z8DmfQoxWmmy"},{"album":{"album_type":"album","artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/album\/1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/albums\/1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4","id":"1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4","images":[{"height":640,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/d5a749a17dfde0529b66ed73bdb979c1b71da74e","width":640},{"height":300,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/a2a119315824287969a97952acdec142b18cbad8","width":300},{"height":64,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/37149c0c69e4237181894c3ac621488f125469e7","width":64}],"name":"Begin Here","release_date":"1965-03-01","release_date_precision":"day","total_tracks":14,"type":"album","uri":"spotify:album:1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4"},"artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"disc_number":1,"duration_ms":136026,"explicit":false,"external_ids":{"isrc":"GBCBS6432200"},"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/track\/2o6sXX0llloUkaUm9DEbLY"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/tracks\/2o6sXX0llloUkaUm9DEbLY","id":"2o6sXX0llloUkaUm9DEbLY","is_local":false,"is_playable":true,"name":"Can't Nobody Love You","popularity":47,"preview_url":"https:\/\/p.scdn.co\/mp3-preview\/f73cf78fefa69be6fe1872d735de2d324d646d09?cid=162b7dc01f3a4a2ca32ed3cec83d1e02","track_number":9,"type":"track","uri":"spotify:track:2o6sXX0llloUkaUm9DEbLY"},{"album":{"album_type":"album","artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/album\/1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/albums\/1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4","id":"1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4","images":[{"height":640,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/d5a749a17dfde0529b66ed73bdb979c1b71da74e","width":640},{"height":300,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/a2a119315824287969a97952acdec142b18cbad8","width":300},{"height":64,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/37149c0c69e4237181894c3ac621488f125469e7","width":64}],"name":"Begin Here","release_date":"1965-03-01","release_date_precision":"day","total_tracks":14,"type":"album","uri":"spotify:album:1vWVHhniWzqyNC0UzDDGs4"},"artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"disc_number":1,"duration_ms":108573,"explicit":false,"external_ids":{"isrc":"GBCBS6432263"},"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/track\/2iSxljzM8Xw9EEIGBRW1CD"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/tracks\/2iSxljzM8Xw9EEIGBRW1CD","id":"2iSxljzM8Xw9EEIGBRW1CD","is_local":false,"is_playable":true,"name":"The Way I Feel Inside","popularity":45,"preview_url":"https:\/\/p.scdn.co\/mp3-preview\/5ada4402121ccad4aa791ce54450705e41b61dd5?cid=162b7dc01f3a4a2ca32ed3cec83d1e02","track_number":4,"type":"track","uri":"spotify:track:2iSxljzM8Xw9EEIGBRW1CD"},{"album":{"album_type":"album","artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/album\/7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/albums\/7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0","id":"7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0","images":[{"height":600,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/0a645e0d3298508d0a090474d998789bd06bfbae","width":600},{"height":300,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/5a2d17c24e4babc3604466e601641bc6341a1f32","width":300},{"height":64,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/3c4308f9778895e9c35f9fd63cb0b33fdf3b3b05","width":64}],"name":"Odessey And Oracle","release_date":"1968-04-19","release_date_precision":"day","total_tracks":12,"type":"album","uri":"spotify:album:7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0"},"artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"disc_number":1,"duration_ms":139093,"explicit":false,"external_ids":{"isrc":"GBCBS6732193"},"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/track\/6BSM7JqYn5wZxl1o3f7oxT"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/tracks\/6BSM7JqYn5wZxl1o3f7oxT","id":"6BSM7JqYn5wZxl1o3f7oxT","is_local":false,"is_playable":true,"name":"A Rose For Emily","popularity":45,"preview_url":"https:\/\/p.scdn.co\/mp3-preview\/355dfc47758c00d89ffbcf9bbefb69af299549c7?cid=162b7dc01f3a4a2ca32ed3cec83d1e02","track_number":2,"type":"track","uri":"spotify:track:6BSM7JqYn5wZxl1o3f7oxT"},{"album":{"album_type":"album","artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/album\/7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/albums\/7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0","id":"7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0","images":[{"height":600,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/0a645e0d3298508d0a090474d998789bd06bfbae","width":600},{"height":300,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/5a2d17c24e4babc3604466e601641bc6341a1f32","width":300},{"height":64,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/3c4308f9778895e9c35f9fd63cb0b33fdf3b3b05","width":64}],"name":"Odessey And Oracle","release_date":"1968-04-19","release_date_precision":"day","total_tracks":12,"type":"album","uri":"spotify:album:7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0"},"artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"disc_number":1,"duration_ms":163733,"explicit":false,"external_ids":{"isrc":"GBCBS6732195"},"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/track\/3R2zCRTwqfD5DCX4XlAsoQ"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/tracks\/3R2zCRTwqfD5DCX4XlAsoQ","id":"3R2zCRTwqfD5DCX4XlAsoQ","is_local":false,"is_playable":true,"name":"Beechwood Park (Mono Version)","popularity":43,"preview_url":"https:\/\/p.scdn.co\/mp3-preview\/812c91a7b15d365c6481f30c860d403484e05f20?cid=162b7dc01f3a4a2ca32ed3cec83d1e02","track_number":4,"type":"track","uri":"spotify:track:3R2zCRTwqfD5DCX4XlAsoQ"},{"album":{"album_type":"compilation","artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/album\/0ttvz9n7vBPaMWpRplAZbs"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/albums\/0ttvz9n7vBPaMWpRplAZbs","id":"0ttvz9n7vBPaMWpRplAZbs","images":[{"height":600,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/96505f6b25ba6c5d48f017cbebe9f606729f0b97","width":600},{"height":300,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/edfaccd8ad5df41b427220bc5ec856368ad5b8d7","width":300},{"height":64,"url":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/e13571723be8407c257fa1340c74fe1ebb96dbb8","width":64}],"name":"The Original Studio Recordings (Volume One)","release_date":"2007-04-30","release_date_precision":"day","total_tracks":20,"type":"album","uri":"spotify:album:0ttvz9n7vBPaMWpRplAZbs"},"artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","id":"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5","name":"The Zombies","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"}],"disc_number":1,"duration_ms":126600,"explicit":false,"external_ids":{"isrc":"GBCBS6432262"},"external_urls":{"spotify":"https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/track\/5FNRngWeBEpR8BiGLlNm2l"},"href":"https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/tracks\/5FNRngWeBEpR8BiGLlNm2l","id":"5FNRngWeBEpR8BiGLlNm2l","is_local":false,"is_playable":true,"name":"Tell Her No","popularity":41,"preview_url":"https:\/\/p.scdn.co\/mp3-preview\/e87062cab3f5ba1e17b3cc01395b9b4ce9c2d996?cid=162b7dc01f3a4a2ca32ed3cec83d1e02","track_number":10,"type":"track","uri":"spotify:track:5FNRngWeBEpR8BiGLlNm2l"}],"insights":{"artist_gid":"4bed34afbb0644ee84410e0774ee0b27","autobiography":{"body":"The 2nd UK band following <a href=\"spotify:artist:3WrFJ7ztbogyGnTHbHJFl2\" data-name=\"The Beatles\">The Beatles<\/a> to score a #1 hit in the US, <a href=\"spotify:artist:2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5\" data-name=\"The Zombies\">The Zombies<\/a> infiltrated airwaves with the sophisticated melodies, choral back-up harmonies and jazzy keyboard riffs of their 60s singles <a href=\"spotify:track:3dzW0SoVNyJTWWJimX8stj\" data-name=\"She's Not There\">She's Not There<\/a> and <a href=\"spotify:track:5FNRngWeBEpR8BiGLlNm2l\" data-name=\"Tell Her No\">Tell Her No<\/a>. Ironically the group broke-up just prior to achieving their greatest success\u2013 the worldwide chart-topping hit <a href=\"spotify:track:5AJrhrwz4oSZX2PwwV4qrN\" data-name=\"Time Of The Season (Mono Version)\">Time Of The Season (Mono Version)<\/a> from <a href=\"spotify:album:7K6JtyaSSVr7HidQsCHun0\" data-name=\"Odessey And Oracle\">Odessey And Oracle<\/a> ranked #100 in Rolling Stone\u2019s \u2018500 Greatest Albums of All Time.\u2019 To this day generations of new bands have cited the band&#39;s work as pop touchstones.\n \nFollowing the break-up of the original band, lead vocalist <a href=\"spotify:artist:27DCwiPx5ocQsf4K43SlIL\" data-name=\"Colin Blunstone\">Colin Blunstone<\/a> went on to develop an acclaimed solo career (<a href=\"spotify:track:20mUVwCxR1x2d5SuBRGW1F\" data-name=\"Say You Don't Mind\">Say You Don't Mind<\/a>, &quot;What Becomes of the Brokenhearted and <a href=\"spotify:track:1VD1jzThUoPSljwULNxbEV\" data-name=\"Old And Wise\">Old And Wise<\/a> with <a href=\"spotify:artist:2RtIpLf0XAoJH6ZqD4i2qQ\" data-name=\"The Alan Parson Project\">The Alan Parson Project<\/a>) and keyboardist\/songwriter Rod Argent rocked arenas with his band <a href=\"spotify:artist:46VosWAvtZsBl7rvxufsWG\" data-name=\"Argent\">Argent<\/a> ( <a href=\"spotify:track:3vfIv3pvYlLOa0wKIEuqFn\" data-name=\"Hold Your Head Up\">Hold Your Head Up<\/a>,&quot; &quot;<a href=\"spotify:track:1qUSBfdnI4rNBZPUwj0rxg\" data-name=\"God Gave Rock and Roll to You\">God Gave Rock and Roll to You<\/a>&quot;) but the legend of The Zombies continued to take on a life of its own. By the start of the new Millennium Blunstone and Argent were inspired to resurrect the band.\n \nThe release of 2015&#39;s <a href=\"spotify:album:59pVA8DVGTfziL0HJ07MR9\" data-name=\"Still Got That Hunger\">Still Got That Hunger<\/a> proved that Zombies fever is stronger than ever with premieres in Rolling Stone, Mojo, The Wall Street Journal, and Spin alongside broadcast performances on Later\u2026With Jools Holland and The Late Show With Stephen Colbert. It marked a historical moment on the Billboard charts as Odessey &amp;amp; Oracle re-entered the Billboard 100 48 years later at the same time as Still Got That Hunger!\n","urls":["https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/The_Zombies"],"links":{"twitter":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/TheZombiesMusic","instagram":"https:\/\/instagram.com\/thezombiesofficial","wikipedia":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/The_Zombies","facebook":"https:\/\/facebook.com\/thezombiesmusic"}},"header_image":{"id":"114df83ef8fb43ecbd250754a7eef627","uri":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/05102b43a3f8cbe9be1d4e53936c3778c38d0058","width":2660,"height":1140},"images":[{"id":"dc83b09e2ff94ef7886d4a9952aad873","uri":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/c054bc1404e67e75c71864fb7eadfcf2b29041a1","width":640,"height":640},{"id":"2468bcc482334def98c2376d6da6f944","uri":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/c250625fd3906f8e48112d2f59628074e7f6be36","width":640,"height":640},{"id":"3c64a1688445434ebb7c9cf4faa26e2c","uri":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/430e69db333d45a5db933df2dcb005950eccfca3","width":640,"height":640},{"id":"6e5c3926ca274ad1ab4144e01a209515","uri":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/1fa01e8b770525b8d02ad57bceed4e73c9b6880e","width":640,"height":640},{"id":"6cd92979664a4ee5bcd3dd3e107bf780","uri":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/8e2ceafe15e67248e6d903153ebe16e937ab4f81","width":640,"height":640},{"id":"85f80fb8369e48548fcc33b06bafa48a","uri":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/d27b37a7399cd76b52f05a0833d8ca7e0e719cc1","width":640,"height":640},{"id":"4e10878d2c554185afc46f492864d8e3","uri":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/fab1f745a76ab01899d366f60b33ffc3229e02d5","width":640,"height":640},{"id":"ecb2c436028d41a8bbeec81a64a983c7","uri":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/69156bbf0749feb4f5f26df2d6f60eb326324104","width":640,"height":640},{"id":"15d319d1ba534f7593450c60db6a1bf3","uri":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/0c74e4d0fc90493ef43805be15632e1bb6ec937f","width":640,"height":640},{"id":"84a3dde02bba447faeeda715aac3301e","uri":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/f0b4757d3ebc0bb9d2dce9d59496c0dfd7969355","width":640,"height":640},{"id":"d0691a830aff410d8e5886995f6120f6","uri":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/2a750b8443331627ac9cdfff9d246b8b28d25f6d","width":640,"height":640},{"id":"ce34afe64fe846c0971971b69731a1ad","uri":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/7d06e4113f7ec3632f5a689b7a14f5cf2dbd2d97","width":640,"height":640}],"global_chart_position":0,"monthly_listeners":1492664,"monthly_listeners_delta":-37419,"follower_count":274041,"following_count":0,"playlists":{"entries":[{"uri":"spotify:user:spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DXaKIA8E7WcJj","name":"All Out 60s","image_url":"https:\/\/pl.scdn.co\/images\/pl\/default\/7d83fe0cbafd08b5572718f353c71025b84244be","owner":{"name":"Spotify","uri":"spotify:user:spotify"},"listeners":162030,"description":"The essential tracks from a decade of revolutions."},{"uri":"spotify:user:spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DWSDoVybeQisg","name":"Psychedelic Rock","image_url":"https:\/\/pl.scdn.co\/images\/pl\/default\/539d8f61c37764d6b70f0fd48165a219faf155d8","owner":{"name":"Spotify","uri":"spotify:user:spotify"},"listeners":38865,"description":"Zone out to some of the best psychedelic rock classics."},{"uri":"spotify:user:spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DXcyVNt8nnPfR","name":"Chilled Classics","image_url":"https:\/\/pl.scdn.co\/images\/pl\/default\/d511f580d51e4094694d280a94c2e4f260152675","owner":{"name":"Spotify","uri":"spotify:user:spotify"},"listeners":27954,"description":"Relax and allow your mind wander with these seriously laid-back classics."},{"uri":"spotify:user:1225379340:playlist:54a4Lsi1OdU4T4XV3ysQBU","name":"Vietnam War Era Music","image_url":"https:\/\/pl.scdn.co\/images\/pl\/default\/2835d6264ec8fde2aaabfb3ec937582018ef13b2","owner":{"name":"Trevor Johnston","uri":"spotify:user:1225379340"},"listeners":27530},{"uri":"spotify:user:spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DX5qNE4zrflL7","name":"Alternative 60s","image_url":"https:\/\/pl.scdn.co\/images\/pl\/default\/4fe7dcd7917b77e67897d4177e384cb864793de0","owner":{"name":"Spotify","uri":"spotify:user:spotify"},"listeners":25356,"description":"The songs that influenced everything that has happened since. Cover: The Rolling Stones"}]},"cities":[{"country":"US","region":"CA","city":"Los Angeles","listeners":43000},{"country":"GB","region":"ENG","city":"London","listeners":35183},{"country":"MX","region":"CMX","city":"Mexico City","listeners":27445},{"country":"US","region":"IL","city":"Chicago","listeners":24011},{"country":"US","region":"NY","city":"New York City","listeners":22582},{"country":"US","region":"CA","city":"San Francisco","listeners":16758},{"country":"US","region":"NY","city":"Brooklyn","listeners":15868},{"country":"US","region":"TX","city":"Dallas","listeners":14429},{"country":"FR","region":"75","city":"Paris","listeners":13131},{"country":"CA","region":"ON","city":"Toronto","listeners":12914},{"country":"US","region":"GA","city":"Atlanta","listeners":12524},{"country":"CL","region":"RM","city":"Santiago","listeners":12452},{"country":"BR","region":"SP","city":"S\u00e3o Paulo","listeners":12403},{"country":"US","region":"TX","city":"Houston","listeners":12353},{"country":"US","region":"WA","city":"Seattle","listeners":11244},{"country":"SE","region":"AB","city":"Stockholm","listeners":10880},{"country":"ES","region":"M","city":"Madrid","listeners":10233},{"country":"US","region":"CO","city":"Denver","listeners":10013},{"country":"AU","region":"QLD","city":"Brisbane","listeners":9141},{"country":"AU","region":"VIC","city":"Melbourne","listeners":9014},{"country":"NZ","region":"AUK","city":"Auckland","listeners":8996},{"country":"IE","region":"L","city":"Dublin","listeners":8832},{"country":"AU","region":"NSW","city":"Sydney","listeners":8590},{"country":"DE","region":"BE","city":"Berlin","listeners":8559},{"country":"US","region":"OR","city":"Portland","listeners":8433},{"country":"CA","region":"QC","city":"Montreal","listeners":8397},{"country":"US","region":"PA","city":"Philadelphia","listeners":7958},{"country":"AU","region":"WA","city":"Perth","listeners":7606},{"country":"NO","region":"03","city":"Oslo","listeners":7487},{"country":"ES","region":"B","city":"Barcelona","listeners":7460},{"country":"US","region":"AZ","city":"Phoenix","listeners":6998},{"country":"AR","region":"C","city":"Buenos Aires","listeners":6621},{"country":"US","region":"DC","city":"Washington","listeners":6560},{"country":"NL","region":"NH","city":"Amsterdam","listeners":6456},{"country":"US","region":"CA","city":"Sacramento","listeners":6139},{"country":"US","region":"NY","city":"The Bronx","listeners":5933},{"country":"US","region":"VA","city":"Arlington","listeners":5827},{"country":"US","region":"MN","city":"Minneapolis","listeners":5782},{"country":"US","region":"TX","city":"Austin","listeners":5568},{"country":"US","region":"FL","city":"Orlando","listeners":5496},{"country":"DE","region":"HH","city":"Hamburg","listeners":5488},{"country":"DK","region":"84","city":"Copenhagen","listeners":5486},{"country":"CA","region":"BC","city":"Vancouver","listeners":5448},{"country":"US","region":"OH","city":"Cleveland","listeners":5446},{"country":"US","region":"MA","city":"Boston","listeners":5357},{"country":"IT","region":"MI","city":"Milan","listeners":5039},{"country":"PE","region":"LMA","city":"Lima","listeners":5007},{"country":"US","region":"CA","city":"Riverside","listeners":4648},{"country":"SE","region":"O","city":"Gothenburg","listeners":4595},{"country":"US","region":"CA","city":"Oakland","listeners":4515}]}};
  </script><script src="https://open.scdn.co/static/landing_page_acq.8c8c93dc.js"></script><script src="https://vt.myvisualiq.net/2/afTxMmlGwCNRJiC5Bd75ug%3D%3D/vt-150.js" async=""></script><!-- Begin comScore Tag --><script>
var _comscore = _comscore || [];
_comscore.push({ c1: "2", c2: "15654041" });
(function() {
  var s = document.createElement("script"), el =
    document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.async = true;
  s.src = "https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js";
  el.parentNode.insertBefore(s, el);
})();
</script><!-- End comScore Tag --></body></html>""", "html.parser")
pattern = re.compile(r"\s+=\s+(\{.*?\});\n")
result = soup.find("script", text=pattern)
```

Sidenotes:

While technically the json could be manually extracted without regex in this case, results are slightly different in various pages

I would like to learn regex, but presently don’t have the bandwidth to start from the ground up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've pasted your example [here](https://regex101.com/r/CZK0E5/2/) and your regex is close to working as intended. Note that `soup.find()` will only return the first result, whereas `soup.find_all()` will return all matches. Regardless, I would suggest that you leverage `re.findall()` here, since you are passing a regex and interpreting the HTML as a `str`:

```
tag = soup.find_all('script')[1]
pattern = re.compile(r"\s+=\s+(\{.*\})")
result = re.findall(pattern, str(tag))
```

Note that both `soup.find_all()` and `re.findall()` return a list of results, and you should find your desired output as the second element in that list. The first element will be `{}`, which stems from this portion of the input text: `'Spotify = {};'`

Comment: This helps, but findall() gives me the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. I tried find_all(), which works, but there is only one element in the list, which is the same string I received with find()

Comment: You're right, it should be `find_all()`. Been working with `re.findall()` too much...I've updated the link in my answer. Ensure that your string and regex match what is there.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the main issue is that even find_all() doesn't solve the problem: When I test it, there is only one item in the list returned, the original string with extra data

Comment: This isn't a problem for me anymore, but it should be noted that, despite the json apparently being extracted, it fails to load via json.loads()

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you can count on certain factors around the JSON you could use something like this:

```
(?<=Spotify\.Entity\s=\s)(\{.*\});
```

This depends on the JSON being set very specifically to `Spotify.Entity =` with the format and spacing as you've written.  The pattern uses a positive look-behind, which means the conditional prefix of the match must be fixed length; hence me not using `\s+` like you did in your original attempt.  Here's an example: https://regex101.com/r/jK5wU3/6

UPDATE: A trivial change leads to more flexibility, though not total and you would now need to grab capture group 1: https://regex101.com/r/aYeZNu/2

Comment: I may be confused here, but using either of those formulas gave me the original string containing extra data than json.

Comment: The first one I list gives you the JSON string only, the second matches more than that but has a group defined in the pattern that would hold just the JSON.  I'm assuming "the JSON" starts with `{"external_urls":` and ends with `"Oakland","listeners":4515}]}}` ; so maybe I'm confused?  If you follow the links the examples show on the right what the selections are and, using my assumptions, correctly select the JSON.

Comment: I was confused. I just reran it (I ran it with the wrong set of variables I think, whatever that means).

Comment: Based on the answer below, it appears that nothing needs to be changed about the formula, just how to use it. I reckon I'll accept that answer as it was posted first. Thanks in any case.