# Extracting a value of an object key from inside the script element in the HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, lxml

```
<div class="heading-dom view">
    <script type="application/javascript">
        window.realty = {"user_id":4243456};
        <!--window.agency = < %- JSON.stringify(agency) % >;-->
        <!--window.agency = < %- JSON.stringify({}) % >-->
     </script>
</div>
```

My desired output is `4243456`. How could I extract it using lxml of beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is overall an interesting problem - extracting something from inside a JavaScript code which is inside the HTML code.

Basically, it means that you first need to do HTML parsing - locate the desired `script` element and get its text. Then, the second step would be to extract the desired number from inside the `realty` object.

If you would go for a regular expression approach, you may actually *re-use a regular expression to both locate the desired `script` element and also to extract the desired variable* (`BeautifulSoup` [allows to apply regular expression patterns](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) to find/filter the elements):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
 <div class="heading-dom view">
     <script type="application/javascript">
        window.realty = {"user_id":4243456};
        <!--window.agency = < %- JSON.stringify(agency) % >;-->
        <!--window.agency = < %- JSON.stringify({}) % >-->
     </script>
</div>"""

pattern = re.compile(r'\{"user_id"\s*:\s*(\d+)\}')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

print(pattern.search(script.text).group(1))
# prints 4243456
```

Let's break down `\{"user_id"\s*:\s*(\d+)\}` here:

- backslashes are used to escape characters that have special meaning in a regular expression syntax
- `\s*` means - zero or more space characters (put it there just in case you are gonna have extra spaces around the `:` in the object definition)
- `\d+` means "one or more digits"
- parenthesis define a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) - that's a way for us to extract a specific part of a string into a group which we then access via `.group(1)`

Note that the simple `\d+` expression suggested by @Evyatar is too broad and you may easily get false positives.

Here are some of the similar topics that contain some other options as well:

- [Extracting text from script tag using BeautifulSoup in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25111752/771848)

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the script tag's text using BeautifulSoup but in order to get the `user_id` you need to use regex

```
# Assuming it's the only number in the script's text
pattern = re.compile('\d+')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
for i in soup.select('script'):
    print(re.findall(pattern, i.text))
```

output

> ['4243456']

Answer (score 1):

String manipulation can be an option if you want to avoid using `regex`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content='''
<div class="heading-dom view">
    <script type="application/javascript">
        window.realty = {"user_id":4243456};
        <!--window.agency = < %- JSON.stringify(agency) % >;-->
        <!--window.agency = < %- JSON.stringify({}) % >-->
     </script>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
item = soup.select('script')[0].text.split('user_id":')[1].split("}")[0]
print(item)
```

Output:

```
4243456
```